# Importing CSV file using Python at a certain time

Tags: python, csv

Suppose we have 50 files in a certain path. they are updated from different people around the world.
the point is to import a CSV file at * a certain time *.
and to import another CSV file at * different time *

For instance, to import CSV file-1 at 10 PM (to be programmable ) and import CSV file-2 at 10:30 PM (to be programmable too ) and so on

the main target to write a code to be run automatically in certain times.

Thanks in advance

Comment: get the system time, and based on it, choose your csv file

Comment: `cron`, [Rocketry](https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.